# iphone encode problem with ffmpeg

Tags: iphone, encoding, ffmpeg

I need to encode a video from image.
I use ffmpeg and compiling rigth.
My problem is that when i try to opne video with quicktime on iphone, this give me a message "this movie format is not supported".
I create a file mp4 with this parameter on context:

```
context->time_base.num = 1;
context->time_base.den = 15;
context->codec_type = CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO;
context->codec_id = CODEC_ID_H264;
context->bit_rate = 1000000;

context->width = width; 
context->height = height;

context->keyint_min = 10;
context->i_quant_factor = 0.71;
context->bit_rate_tolerance = 20000;
context->rc_max_rate = 100000;
context->rc_buffer_size = 8835000;
context->qcompress = 0.6;
context->qmin = 10;
context->qmax = 30;
context->max_qdiff = 4;
context->gop_size = 30;

context->time_base.num = 1;

context->time_base.den = 30;
context->sample_aspect_ratio = av_d2q(1, 255);
context->profile = 30;

context->pix_fmt =  PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

context->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_LOOP_FILTER;
```

where is my mistake??
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use AVFoundation instead, that lets you use the hardware acceleration when encoding.